# Policy on top secret answers?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

There is much technology that is not public in aerospace. What is the policy about that information here as posts?

Comment: In terms of US information security, anyone knowing classified information (whether SBU, Secret, Top Secret, or other) may not legally post that information here. Anyone who knows the information and knows its classification level and sees it posted here should report it as a leak (and may be required to by law). An Aviation.SE policy seems like it would be besides the point. Generally we shouldn't expect to see any classified information on Aviation.SE, since it would not be hard to track down the poster of that information and prosecute them.

Comment: @ToddWilcox That is a great answer.

Comment: This question is somewhat related:  https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/258/69

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is not public and/or based on publicly available information, it means that is basically opinion-based, and as such is off-topic in my opinion.

The alternative is to have a question that will not be answered until such information becomes public (if it ever will happen) but invites speculation in the meanwhile.